# How to compile correctly win64a.file

Tags: assembly, x86-64, masm, masm32

I have this 64-bit assembly code:

```
include win64a.inc

MAXSCREENX = 80
MAXSCREENY = 25
buffersize = 100
.code
WinMain proc
local ConsoleWindow:SMALL_RECT
local cci:CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO
local BUFF[buffersize]:byte
local result:qword
local fdwSaveOldMode:qword
    push    rbp
    mov ebp,esp
    sub esp,(28h+sizeof SMALL_RECT+sizeof CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO+buffersize+\
    2*8+4+15)and(-16)
    xor ebx,ebx
; initialization of the console
    call    FreeConsole
        call    AllocConsole
; to receive input handle
        mov ecx,STD_INPUT_HANDLE
        call    GetStdHandle
        mov hIn,eax
; to receive output handle
        mov ecx,STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
        call    GetStdHandle
        mov hOut,eax
        mov ecx,eax ;hOut
    call    GetLargestConsoleWindowSize
;   eax return in 31-16 bits: dwCoord.y
;                 15-00 bits: dwCoord.x

        lea r8d,ConsoleWindow       ; lpConsoleWindow
    mov [r8],ebx
;   ConsoleWindow.Left = 0  ConsoleWindow.Top = 0

    sub ax, MAXSCREENX
    sbb edx, edx
    and ax, dx
    add ax, MAXSCREENX-1
    mov [r8+SMALL_RECT.Right],ax

    shr eax, 16
    sub eax, MAXSCREENY
    sbb edx, edx
    and eax, edx
    add eax, MAXSCREENY-1
    mov [r8+SMALL_RECT.Bottom],ax
    mov edx,TRUE            ; bAbsolute
    mov ecx,hOut            ; hConsoleOutput
    call    SetConsoleWindowInfo

    mov edx,MAXSCREENY*10000h+MAXSCREENX;dwCoord
    mov ecx,hOut            ; hConsoleOutput
    call    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize  ;establish the new size of console window
    mov ecx,offset NameConsole
    call    SetConsoleTitle
;hide cursor----------------------------------------
    lea edx,cci             ; lpConsoleCursorInfo
    mov ecx,hOut            ; hConsoleOutput
    call    GetConsoleCursorInfo
    lea edx,cci             ; lpConsoleCursorInfo
    mov [rdx+CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO.bVisible],ebx;FALSE
    mov ecx,hOut            ; hConsoleOutput
    call    SetConsoleCursorInfo
;------------------------------------------------------
;keep the current mode of input for future restoration at an exit from the program
    lea edx,fdwSaveOldMode
    mov ecx,hIn
        call    GetConsoleMode
;include input events from a mouse and a window
    mov edx,ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT or ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT
    mov ecx,hIn
    call    SetConsoleMode
;-------------------------------------------------------
    mov [rsp+20h],rbx
    lea r9d,result      ;&result
        mov r8d,sizeof s00
    mov edx,offset s00;'For an exit from the program press "cross" in the right top corner'
    mov ecx,hOut
        call    WriteConsole
; establish the event handler
    mov edx,TRUE
    mov ecx,offset CtrlHandler
    call    SetConsoleCtrlHandler
; procedure with an operation cycle of messages
    call inputcons
; exit
; disconnect the event handler
        mov edx,FALSE
    mov ecx,offset CtrlHandler
    call    SetConsoleCtrlHandler
; restore the current mode of input
        mov rdx,fdwSaveOldMode
    mov ecx,hIn
        call    SetConsoleMode
; release descriptors
    mov ecx,hOut
    call    CloseHandle
    mov ecx,hIn
    call    CloseHandle
; switch off the console
        call    FreeConsole
    xor ecx,ecx
        call    ExitProcess
WinMain endp

; handler of critical console events
CtrlHandler proc fdwCtrlType:qword
    sub esp,28h
    cmp ecx,CTRL_C_EVENT
    jz  beep
    cmp ecx,CTRL_BREAK_EVENT
    jz  beep
    cmp ecx,CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT
    jz  beep
    cmp ecx,CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT
    jz  false
    cmp ecx,CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT
    jz  false
;   another code
false:  xor eax,eax
    jmp bye_bye
beep:   mov edx,1000
    mov ecx,1000
        call    Beep
    mov eax,TRUE
bye_bye:add esp,28h
    retn 
CtrlHandler endp

inputcons   proc
local result:qword
local MOUSE_KEY:INPUT_RECORD
local BUFF[buffersize]:byte
    
;Cycle of reading and processing of events of input
;Expectation of events
    push    rbp
    mov ebp,esp
    sub esp,(28h+buffersize+sizeof INPUT_RECORD+8+15)and(-16)
loo:    lea r9d,result;number of the read symbols
    mov r8d,1     ;reading buffer size
    lea edx,MOUSE_KEY;the buffer in which we read
    mov ecx,hIn   ;input buffer descriptor
    call    ReadConsoleInput
; check correctness of performance of function
    or  eax,eax
    jnz no_err
; error message
        mov [rsp+20h],rbx
    lea r9d,result      ;&result
        mov r8d,sizeof s01
    mov edx,offset s01  ;"Error input!"
    mov ecx,hOut
        call    WriteConsole
    mov ecx,5000
    call    Sleep
    leave
    ret

no_err: lea eax,result
    mov [rsp+20h],rax;number of the read symbols
    mov r9d,1*10000h+0;Y=1 X=0 coordinates of the first symbol - we will begin with 
;the first cell of the second line (on the first line the inscription "For an Exit from the 
;Program Press "Cross" in the Right Top Corner")
    mov r8d,MAXSCREENX*(MAXSCREENY-1);fill area of the screen buffer
;80 ő 24 ńčěâîëîâ íóë˙ěč
    xor edx,edx         ;0 is symbol with which fill
    mov ecx,hOut            ;descriptor of the screen buffer
    call    FillConsoleOutputCharacter;before a conclusion of each message we clear the screen
    mov edx,10*10000h+0 ;Y=10 X=0
        mov ecx,hOut
        call    SetConsoleCursorPosition
;send events to the corresponding handlers
    lea     eax,MOUSE_KEY
    cmp     [rax+INPUT_RECORD.EventType],KEY_EVENT;1
;keyboard input
    jz  KeyEventProc
        cmp     [rax+INPUT_RECORD.EventType],MOUSE_EVENT;2
;input from a mouse
    jz  MouseEventProc
        cmp     [rax+INPUT_RECORD.EventType],WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_EVENT;4
;change of the size of the screen buffer
    jz      ResizeEventProc
    cmp     [rax+INPUT_RECORD.EventType],FOCUS_EVENT;16
;ignoring of events of focus
    jz      loo
    cmp     [rax+INPUT_RECORD.EventType],MENU_EVENT;8
;ignoring of events of the menu
        jz      loo
        mov [rsp+20h],rbx
    lea r9d,result      ;&result
        mov r8d,sizeof s15
    mov edx,offset s15  ;"unknown event type"
    mov ecx,hOut
        call    WriteConsole
        jmp     loo
ResizeEventProc:
    movzx   r9d,MOUSE_KEY.WindowBufferSizeEvent.dwSize.y
        movzx   r8d,MOUSE_KEY.WindowBufferSizeEvent.dwSize.x
        mov     edx,offset xy2       ;'Size of console: Right=%d, Bottom=%d'
    lea ecx,BUFF
    call    wsprintf
    mov [rsp+20h],rbx
    lea r9d,result      ;&result
        mov r8d,eax
    lea edx,BUFF
    mov ecx,hOut
        call    WriteConsole
    mov ecx,5000
    call    Sleep
        jmp     loo
; check the control keys
KeyEventProc:
ok1:    test    [rax+INPUT_RECORD.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState],CAPSLOCK_ON;80h
    jnz dal0
    cmp     [rax+INPUT_RECORD.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState],ENHANCED_KEY;100h
    jz  dal1
    test    [rax+INPUT_RECORD.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState],LEFT_ALT_PRESSED or RIGHT_ALT_PRESSED;2 or 1
    jnz dal2
    test    [rax+INPUT_RECORD.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState],LEFT_CTRL_PRESSED or RIGHT_CTRL_PRESSED;8 or 4
    jnz dal4
    cmp     [rax+INPUT_RECORD.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState],SHIFT_PRESSED;10h
    jz  dal6
    test    [rax+INPUT_RECORD.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState],NUMLOCK_ON;20h
    jnz dal7
    cmp     [rax+INPUT_RECORD.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState],SCROLLLOCK_ON;40h
    jnz us_key
dal8:; SCROLL LOCK
    mov [rsp+20h],rbx;0
        lea r9d,result
    mov r8d,sizeof s11
    mov edx,offset s11  ;"SCROLLLOCK",10
    jmp exit1
MouseEventProc:
    cmp MOUSE_KEY.MouseEvent.dwEventFlags,DOUBLE_CLICK
    jz  dalm0
    cmp MOUSE_KEY.MouseEvent.dwEventFlags,MOUSE_MOVED
    jz  dalm1
        cmp MOUSE_KEY.MouseEvent.dwEventFlags,MOUSE_WHEELED
    jz  dalm2
    cmp MOUSE_KEY.MouseEvent.dwButtonState,FROM_LEFT_1ST_BUTTON_PRESSED
    jz  dalm3
dalm4:  cmp MOUSE_KEY.MouseEvent.dwButtonState,RIGHTMOST_BUTTON_PRESSED
    jnz loo
        mov [rsp+20h],rbx;0
        lea r9d,result             ;&result
    mov r8d,sizeof s07
    mov edx,offset s07  ;"Right mouse click"
    jmp     exit2
dalm0:  mov [rsp+20h],rbx;0
        lea r9d,result             ;&result
    mov r8d,sizeof s03
    mov edx,offset s03      ;"Double click"
    jmp exit2
dalm2:; ęîëĺńčęî ěűřč
        mov [rsp+20h],rbx;0
        lea r9d,result             ;&result
        mov r8d,sizeof s02
    mov edx,offset s02      ;"Wheel was rolled"
    jmp exit2
dalm3:  mov [rsp+20h],rbx;0
        lea r9d,result             ;&result
        mov r8d,sizeof s14
    mov     edx,offset s14      ;"Left mouse click"
    jmp exit2
dalm1:  movzx   r9d,MOUSE_KEY.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.y
        movzx   r8d,MOUSE_KEY.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.x
        mov     edx,offset xy1       ;'Location of cursor: X=%d, Y=%d'
    lea ecx,BUFF
    call    wsprintf
        jmp exit3
dal0:;CAPSLOCK
    mov [rsp+20h],rbx;0
        lea r9d,result             ;&result
        mov r8d,sizeof s09
    mov edx,offset s09      ;"CAPSLOCK",10
    jmp exit1
dal2:; ëĺâűé ALT
        mov [rsp+20h],rbx;0
        lea r9d,result  ;&result
    mov r8d,sizeof s05 
    mov     edx,offset s05      ;"ALT"
        jmp exit1
dal4:; ëĺâűé CTRL
    mov [rsp+20h],rbx;0
        lea r9d,result  ;&result
    mov r8d,sizeof s04 
    mov     edx,offset s04       ;"CTRL"
    jmp exit1
dal6:; SHIFT
    mov [rsp+20h],rbx;0
        lea r9d,result  ;&result
    mov r8d,sizeof s06 
    mov edx,offset s06      ;"SHIFT"
    jmp exit1
dal7:; NUM LOCK
    mov [rsp+20h],rbx;0
        lea r9d,result  ;&result
    mov r8d,sizeof s10 
    mov edx,offset s10      ;"NUMLOCK"
exit1:  mov     ecx,hOut
        call    WriteConsole
; usual keys
us_key: movzx   eax,MOUSE_KEY.KeyEvent.AsciiChar
    cmp al,32
    jb  bel
; symbol output
    mov r8d,eax
    mov edx,offset fc      ;"Character '%c'",0
    jmp exit4
bel:    cmp al,0
    jnz upr
;call these keys functional for them ASCII code it is equal to 0
        movzx   r8d,MOUSE_KEY.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode
    mov edx,offset s13     ;"Function key (virtual code) %d",0
    jmp exit4
upr:    mov r8d,eax
    mov     edx,offset s08     ;"Code %d ",0
    jmp exit4
dal1:; enhanced keyboard
    movzx   r8d,MOUSE_KEY.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode
    mov edx,offset s12     ;"Enhanced key (virtual code) %d",0
exit4:  lea ecx,BUFF
    call    wsprintf
exit3:  mov [rsp+20h],rbx;0
    lea r9d,result  ;&result
    mov r8d,eax
    lea edx,BUFF
exit2:
    mov     ecx,hOut
        call    WriteConsole
        jmp loo
inputcons   endp
;------------------------------------------------------     
NameConsole db 'Processing of mouse and keyboard messages',0
s00 db 'For an exit from the program press "cross" in the right top corner'
s01 db "Error input!"
s02 db "Wheel was rolled"
s03 db "Double click"
s04 db "CTRL",10
s05 db "ALT",10
s06 db "SHIFT",10
s07 db "Right mouse click"
s08 db "Code %d ",0
s09 db "CAPSLOCK",10
s10 db "NUMLOCK",10
s11 db "SCROLLLOCK",10
s12 db "Enhanced key (virtual code) %d",0
s13 db "Function key (virtual code) %d",0
s14 db "Left mouse click"
s15 db "Unknown event type"
s16 db "Change of the sizes of the screen buffer"
fc  db "Character '%c'",0
xy1 db 'Location of cursor: X=%d, Y=%d',0
xy2 db 'Size of console: Right=%d, Bottom=%d',0
hIn dd ?
hOut    dd ?
end
```

When I assemble the code it gives this error:

[image]

Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: The MASM32 SDK (MASM version  6.14) is only a 32-bit assembler, and doesn't understand 64-bit code. You will need a newer version of MASM (ML64.EXE) from a more recent MASM, or something like JWASM.

Comment: The copyright notice on your ancient assembler is a clue: (C) MS 1981-1997.  But AMD64 was only proposed on paper in about 2000, and real silicon sold in ~2003.

Comment: @MichaelPetch and were can i download properly MASM (ML64.EXE) ?

Comment: And how can i compile it with JWASM because it showed me similar error

Comment: You can get ML64 with any of the free Community versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: WIn64a.inc may be a FASM include. Where did you get Win64a.inc from? You may need to get Win64.inc for MASM

Comment: @MichaelPetch I tried also Win64.inc but it showed an error again